# TypeError: this.graphInspector.insertEnhancerMetadataCache is not a function

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nest, supertest

I am working with NestJS, Jest and Supertest. I created a spec file to test my controller.

The spec file:

```
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IzvodiNalogModule } from './izvodi_nalog.module';
import { AppModule } from 'src/app.module';

describe('izvodi_nalog', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule, IzvodiNalogModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it(`/GET find modal fields`, async () => {
    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/izvodi/modal-data')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200);

    expect(response.body).toBeDefined();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

I run yarn jest -- name-of-file.spec.ts and get:

```
➜  izvodi-api git:(krd-620-unos-novog-izvoda) ✗ yarn jest -- izvodi_nalog.controller.spec.ts
 FAIL  src/tenants/partner/modules/izvodi_nalog/izvodi_nalog.controller.spec.ts (7.596 s)
  ● izvodi_nalog › /GET find modal fields

    TypeError: this.graphInspector.insertEnhancerMetadataCache is not a function

      at DependenciesScanner.insertInjectable (../../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:259:33)
      at ../../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:147:66
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:147:39
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at DependenciesScanner.reflectInjectables (../../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:146:27)
      at DependenciesScanner.reflectDynamicMetadata (../../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:124:14)
      at ../../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:114:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at DependenciesScanner.reflectControllers (../../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:112:21)


  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')

      28 |
      29 |   afterAll(async () => {
    > 30 |     await app.close();
         |               ^
      31 |   });
      32 | });
      33 |

      at tenants/partner/modules/izvodi_nalog/izvodi_nalog.controller.spec.ts:30:15

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.656 s
Ran all test suites matching /izvodi_nalog.controller.spec.ts/i.
```

Further context:
I am working on a monorepo made by my company, so I doubt there are any errors in the package.json. I also tried running all test in a different package inside the monorepo, whose code is on main and therefore should be bulletproof and tested and still get the same error and all of the tests failing, so I doubt its because of the code.

If anyone on here might have any idea whats going on, please enlighten me. I plan on asking my mentors about it but first I want to atleast get some insight into the problem so I don't come off as an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the version of `@nestjs/testing` matches the version of `@nestjs/core`. If you are updating NestJS via the `nest update --force` command, it will only update `@nestjs/core`, which will break tests.